# Non-indexeed properties in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone explain how the result of `RegExp.prototype.exec` is made?

If you try something like that: `/d/g.exec("d is a character, dd")` the result is an array structured as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

My question is, **how the array has non-indexeed** properties like `index` and `input`**?**

Normally an array is a collection indexeed by integers (`[0...n]`);

```js
var re = /d/g;
var str = "domains are always domains";

var result = re.exec(str);

console.log("typeof result", typeof result);
console.log("Array.isArray(result)", Array.isArray(result));
console.log("result.length", result.length);
console.log("result", result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is just an object. In fact, you can make simple array-like objects just like that:

```
var fakeArr = {}
fakeArr[0] = 'foo';
fakeArr[1] = 'bar';
fakeArr.length = 2;
```

The only thing that distinguishes an array from a plain object is the behaviour of the `.length` property and the various array-specific methods on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: I don't think this is, or, at least, that's not all. For example, what `Array.isArray(fakeArr)` returns?

Comment: `isArray` would return `false`, because it checks whether the object inherits from `Array`, which in this case it obviously doesn't. That's why I said *array-like*. There are other *array-like* objects, for example [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) (it is officially documented as *array-like*). That means you can *iterate* it like an array (`for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)`), but it does not have full array characteristics.

Comment: And yes, that's really all there is to it. An array is a plain object + some extra properties and methods.

Comment: I could accept your answer if you make edits including, for example, the Array inheritance... that makes fakeArr iterable (`var fakeArr = Object.create(Array.prototype)`)

Comment: `fakeArr` *is* iterable. Classic Javascript iteration happens with a `for` loop. All you need for that is a `length` property. Recent Javascript editions add a lot of alternative methods like `forEach`, but those are not in any way necessary to iterate an array.

Comment: that answer doesn't address the OP, I was asking for Arrays, not else. I provided examples too and bolded some parts. Basically, I'm not talking about objects that are int-indexeed, but arrays that are not.

Comment: Well, the answer is: **because an array is an object**, and you can obviously set any arbitrary properties on objects.